# Should potentially useful self-deleted questions be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454419/how-can-i-get-the-different-icon-sizes-from-a-file-extension) the OP was greeted by a barrage of mixed comments, both positive and negative.

In response to that the OP edited the question to add a link to a post that holds an answer that doesn't work for him. After that the OP decided to delete his question.<sup>1</sup>

Here is a screenshot for <10K:

[image: Screenshot]

I searched for a possible answer and the ones I found (even on off-site resources) are incomplete at best and the link to a possible duplicate provide in the comments leads to an almost link-only answer that I'm happy to flag.

Can we undelete<sup>1</sup> the question so a proper answer can be provided? Or am I getting mellow?

<sup>1. The question has been undeleted since, closed and then re-opened.</sup>

Comment: If you salvage the question, what are the odds it will get answered (potentially, better than your current findings) and accepted without the original author's support?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: Because that's what questions at SO exist for.

Comment: I can't predict the future but I see no reason to expect  that it will remain unanswered.

Comment: If the problem exists for more than one person, another fellow will ask it someday.

Comment: The problem exists for the OP and he did what the site is designed for: asked a question. Why does he now have to wait for another fellow to ask it?

Comment: He doesn't. He chose that himself.

Comment: Okay, that does it for the 1st question. Here's the second one:
Who will you attribute the restored question to if you restore it? Original author who showed insufficient mental stability for this task and may probably be less-than-happy with you overriding their decision and bringing another turmoil upon them? Yourself? Or you're going to babysit the OP somehow?

Comment: I don't care about the OP. I care about the question. If it goes in a delete/un-delete war I'm out...

Comment: @ivan, *who will you attribute the restored question to if you restore it?* Attribute? Why should we have to "attribute" anything? Questions at SO do not exist for being "attributed".

Comment: No, but the author is seen as the question's primary champion. They are the person most interested in getting the answer in the immediate vicinity (if not outright provide the info necessary to give an answer) and judge the answers' correctness.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev If the question is already a quality question in need of no additional information from the author, then they are not needed *anymore* for the sake of editing the question, and they are *not* the primary judge of answers' correctness, the community is, through voting.  The community  is far more effective at evaluating answers and providing the appropriate feedback than the question author will be.

Comment: Whether or not you undelete this question -- I could really care less -- it would be nice if we did not accuse new users to the site of being mentally unstable.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev You are incorrect. Once content has been posted on Stack Overflow, it is no longer the property of the poster. Questions on SO exist to provide a pointer to a resource (answers) for programming. Who asks the questions and who answers them are both irrelevant.

Comment: Why is everyone calling the OP a new user? They've had the account for 2 years.

Comment: Maybe I should have said low rep @remyabel  which I fixed now in the title

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this question.  Friendly treatment of all users is very important, in my opinion.

Comment: @minitech Why edit the image and link to https?

Comment: @Doorknob: Mixed content blocking makes it not show up on HTTPS meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: @hichris123: Protocol-relative URLs don’t work on the mobile app, apparently.

Comment: Welp, I guess bug report time @minitech.

Comment: Posted a bug report on mSE @minitech: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248569/protocol-relative-links-do-not-work-on-the-android-app

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a significant subjective factor in this... but here's my take.

General principle: **If undeleting a question is a net gain for SO, then yes, we should undelete it.** To be a net gain, it needs to be a well-formulated question, one which is not close-worthy. I'll gladly undelete such questions, especially if they have good answers. (0-score answers don't prevent questions from being deleted so sometimes good answers get deleted because their question was.)

**The problem with this question is that it is not clear that it is a net gain for SO.** I don't agree with the custom close reason that was used but the question is a duplicate of [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701263/get-the-icon-for-a-given-extension). And yes, accepted answer there does fully answers the question we are talking about here, sizes and all. In the off-chance that there is in fact still a problem remaining, then the question that was deleted (and is now undeleted) should be edited to specify what problem exactly still remains.

It could be the case here that the OP of the deleted question followed the link to the other question in the comments, read the answer there, read the document that answer was pointing to and thought "yep, my question is answered", and deleted their own question. Sometimes the OP will comment "yes, that question fully answers mine" before deleting. It did not happen here but the OP could still have decided their question answered. While it's true we do not make a practice of deleting duplicates, there is no hard and fast rule saying that duplicates must *not ever* be deleted.