# When should I vote to undelete an answer deleted by the poster?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I assigned a bounty to one of my questions to attract more attention. The bounty system worked, and in a fairly short amount of time (within 2 days) I got two answers that worked.

I upvoted each answer, posted a comment on each answer (I had some small clarifications, but nothing that would have affected my opinion of either answer answering what I had asked), and said I was going to wait for some time before assigning the bounty (in case other answers came in). In other words, I don't *think* that I was providing a moving goalpost, but just asking for clarifications about the approaches I had already received.

In the meantime, one author decided to update his answer with further details, even complementing the other author on their approach. The other author decided to delete their answer.

I would like to have the deleted answer restored as an answer to the question, because I also liked the approach the user had taken. At the same time, I'm not sure whether I *should* vote to undelete or not. After all, perhaps something in my actions had prompted this behavior.

Should I vote to undelete? Or should I let things be?

<sup>Note: The bounty is still active, so those of you with the powers to see deleted answers shouldn't have any trouble doing so. If it would be helpful to share the question and answer, I can do so, but I thought I would post the question as a general open question.</sup>

Comment: I can't judge the content but maybe the comments and the suggestions in the other answer were misinterpreted by the OP and seen as critique on their answer. As it stands I see some value being lost so I would say undeleting is warranted.

Comment: First of all thank you @rene to notify me. Ananda Mahto ask that guy, if he doesn't like my answer, I'll delete it.

Comment: @alirezasafian, I don't think that would be the solution. Your answer is also spot on, and your elaborations after my comment are also very useful.

Comment: Related: [Should potentially useful self deleted questions be undeleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285841)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There can't be a generic rule that applies to all cases. Undeleting is something that needs to be done on a case-by-case basis.

The user of the other answer is a regular of the same chat room I visit now and then so we discussed this case a little bit.

My impression is that some value is lost by having that answer deleted. Moreover the current visible answer mentions the deleted answer which makes that answer less valuable.

Given those observations I would personally vote to undelete. It would at least give us a chance to ask the OP why they wanted their post deleted in the first place. If that exchange brings forward new information deletion can take place again, maybe after any valuable bits are edit in the remaining answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was originally wondering if I should track down the other author at one of his other answers to see if I could get a response on why it was deleted, but that would be abuse of the system. Undeleting to make this discussion possible seems like a reasonable suggestion.